# Why should we always handle the err function parameter?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Event-driven paradigm in JavaScript adds richness to the language, imagine the browser as this event-driven machine, errors have a similar behavior. An event gets thrown at some point when an error occurs. In theory, we can argue that errors are simple events in JavaScript.

> In the world of error handling there are at least two approaches. One is the fail-silent approach where you ignore errors in the code. The other is the fail-fast and unwind approach where errors stop the world and rewind.

Source: [A Guide to Proper Error Handling in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/proper-error-handling-javascript/)

On the other hand [JavaScript Standard Style Rules](http://standardjs.com/rules.html) use the next example to affirm that we always handle the `err` function parameter:

**Option 1**

```
// ✓ ok 
run(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  window.alert('done')
})
```

**Option 2**

```
// ✗ avoid 
run(function (err) {
  window.alert('done')
})
```

Why we always handle the `err` function parameter?

Comment: Because if you don't handle errors, other errors will occur that eventually cause your entire program to fail. Being able to simply ignore errors without any repercussions is *very* rare.

Comment: You can answer that @Bergi. I think for me is a valid answer with some more information and some more arguments.